# Mailer unable to access reset_token in User model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sidekiq, attr-accessor

faced with an issue where @user.reset_token returns nil.

app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

Reset_token is declared in User model, whereby this problem happens when I try to use a sidekiq worker. Refer to code below.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :reset_token

  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end  

  def send_password_reset_email
    PasswordResetWorker.perform_async(self.id)
  end  

private

  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end
```

app/workers/password_reset_worker.rb

```
class PasswordResetWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    UserMailer.password_reset(user).deliver
  end
end
```

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@example.com"

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password Reset"
  end
end
```

This problem DOES NOT happen when I do not use workers

app/models/user.rb

```
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end
```

Would like to know what can I replace "@user.reset_token" with? Let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The password reset feature is built according to https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset. I only want to add sidekiq for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not storing the `reset_token` in the database - you're storing the `reset_digest`.

When you don't use workers, you're storing the `reset_token` in the User instance, then passing that same User instance to your mailer - hence the `reset_token` is still available.

When you use workers, your worker only has the User's ID, so it's reloading the User instance from the database. Because the `reset_token` isn't being stored in the database, it's coming back nil.

Either you should be saving the `reset_token` in the database, or your password email should be using `reset_digest` in the URL.

Comment: Hey thanks! Yeah, i suspected as much. Any chance I can still do this without needing to save reset_token in the database or use reset_digest? I think it is done this way for security.

Comment: Storing the tokens and then using the tokens to authenticate is okay, as long as the token is sufficiently complex.

Comment: If you're really concerned about security, you can pass the generated `reset_token` as an extra parameter to the Sidekiq worker. Using the tokens directly is sufficient though, as password resets should be short-lived things with a relatively short expiry time.