# ActionMailer can't find reset_token, reports missing :id key

Tags: actionmailer, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-activejob

I'm using [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) as my `ActiveJob` queuing backend, and I'm trying to send out emails using `ActionMailer`'s `deliver_later` method. I believe I've got all of Delayed Job's setup correct, and I'm running a background worker on my development machine.

When I send out a password reset email, I receive the following error:

> [Worker(host:Computer pid:7240)] Job
>   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=1) FAILED
>   (5 prior attempts) with ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches
>   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets",
>   :email=>"user@example.com", :id=> nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Here is how I'm sending out the password reset email. This is located in my `User` model:

```
def send_password_reset_email
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_later
end
```

My password reset setup is very similar to the one on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883926/mailer-unable-to-access-attr-accessor-in-model) in that I don't store my `reset_token` in the database and instead have it as a virtual attribute, and I think that might be my issue, but I want to avoid storing that value if possible. Is there a way I can pass the generated `reset_token` to the Delayed Job worker? It is also possible that my problem is related to something else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I had the answer all along; I had to store my `reset_token` in the database. I'll copy the answer from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883926/mailer-unable-to-access-attr-accessor-in-model/27883959#27883959) below. Credit goes to **sevenseacat** for the answer.

> When you don't use workers, you're storing the `reset_token` in the User
>   instance, then passing that same User instance to your mailer - hence
>   the `reset_token` is still available.
>
> When you use workers, your worker only has the User's ID, so it's
>   reloading the User instance from the database. Because the `reset_token`
>   isn't being stored in the database, it's coming back nil.
>
> Either you should be saving the `reset_token` in the database, or your
>   password email should be using `reset_digest` in the URL

After I changed my `reset_token` from a virtual attribute to a database column, the issue was resolved. My password reset emails are now being sent out.

**EDIT (January 18, 2016)**

I wanted to add a little extra information explaining why the `reset_token` solved the issue even though the error message claimed that the `id` was missing. In my password reset email, I generate the `edit` password reset action URL as follows:

```
<%= edit_password_resets_path(@user.reset_token) %>
```

The route for my edit password reset action is as follows:

```
edit_password_resets   GET   /password_resets/:id/edit
```

When creating a URL, the first parameter that you specify fills in the `:id` segment of the URL. In my case, `@user.reset_token` was being filled in for the `id`, causing the generated URL to be `/password_resets/{reset token here}/edit`. When the async job was trying to generate the URL, it was expecting a value to be specified for the `id` segment of the URL. I put my `reset_token` in for the `id`, and since `reset_token` was a virtual attribute and was equal to `nil` when `ActiveJob` ran, it threw an error since it was missing a value.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to solve a similar problem myself and came to a slightly different solution. To avoid storing the reset token in the database you can refactor your `UserMailer.password_reset(self)` to take two parameters `UserMailer.password_reset(self, self.reset_token)`. Then create two instance variables to pass to the mailer template:

```
@user = user
@reset_token = reset_token
```

and finally in the mailer template itself, you can just do:

```
<%= edit_password_resets_path(@reset_token) %>`
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Shortly after I wrote my solution, I went a route similar to this as well. I created a separate job and passed the password reset token into the job payload as follows: This code is called in the `User` model.

`SendPasswordResetJob.perform_later(self.id, self.password_reset_token)`